# How to handle formset for multiple instances?

Tags: python, django, formset

I'm building a match system for a Tournament Manager. I have a "Match" model and "Set" model (code down below). First, I'd like to have a form that regroups all sets related to one match, how can I do that ? Secondly, how can I handle this if I have several matchs in my template ?

**`models.py`**

```
class Match(models.Model):
    isFinished  = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    team1Win    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    team2Win    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    phase       = models.ForeignKey(Phase, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    teams       = models.ManyToManyField(Team, default=None, blank=True)

class Set(models.Model):
    timeSet     = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    scoreTeam1  = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    scoreTeam2  = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    match       = models.ForeignKey(Match, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**`models.py`**

```
class SetUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Set
        fields = [
            'scoreTeam1',
            'scoreTeam2',
            'match',
        ]
```

EDIT:
I created my formset, etc... All works perfectly good but I want to make some validation before submitting the formset, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to create an inlineformset that will map the Match and all related Set.

First you need the Match and all related Set:

```
#I assume you have the match pk from the url
def match_formset_view(request,pk):
    match = get_object_or_404(Match, pk = pk)
    #get all the related Set
    sets = match.set_set.all()
    #create the inline formset
    MatchSetFormset = forms.inlineformset_factory(
        Match,
        Set,
        form=SetUpdateForm,
        min_num=1,
        extra=0,
        can_delete=True
    )

    #populate the formset accordingly
    formset = MatchSetFormset(request.POST or None,instance=match, queryset= sets,prefix='sets')
    #validate the formset
    if formset.is_valid():
        #do something then save
        formset.save()
    else:
        #do other things.
```

Be aware that you can't save the formset if you didn't save the Match instance first(for creation).

Comment: The thing is that I'm handling all matchs at the same time. I have a queryset : ```matches = Match.objects.filter(phase=phase)```